# How do I move an object back into my view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I accidentally removed an object from a view into the canvas.  How can I add it back?  I have a simple example, but this happened on a bigger scale, so I don't what to recreate all the objects.

When I drag it back it isn't in the view it's just overtop of it.

[image: object]

Thanks

Comment: Here is an [image](http://i.imgur.com/r3jn9.png) that shows Alan Moore's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand the folder view on the left side where you currently just see the icons, click the little arrow next to the search bar on the bottom left corner of that section.  Then, in that section, grab the view and you can drag the view under the larger view "folder" of the page.  Hope that helps, its a little hard to explain.

Comment: Thanks so very much.  I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me.